# FME linux path - cannot locate VRT

Tags: raster, fme-form, linux, file-path

I am trying to transfer an FMW (FME workspace) script, using FME workbench 2020.2, from windows to linux (Redhat).

In the FMW-script there are several published parameters. Among them there are 2 parameters. One for our DTM-raster .vrt file (parameter name = "DTM_dataset") and one similar to our DSM .vrt file (parameter name = 'DSM_dataset'). I have tried giving the published parameters the path to these .vrt-files both manually writing them and using the "Open file browser" option.

edited addition: these published parameters are transferred through a workspacerunner to another FMW-script, which have the same published parameters.

the paths given to FME are like this:

```
# linux path
/path/to/vrt/file/DSM.vrt
```

In both cases, the Translation log, and our logfile gives us this message:

```
2022-03-28 10:36:45|   0.9|  0.0|ERROR |VRT_RASTER reader: dataset '<solidus>path<solidus>to<solidus>vrt<solidus>file<solidus>DSM.vrt' cannot be located.  Please ensure the dataset exists and is accessible
```

and the weird part:

If i don't use the published parameters, but instead write the DSM-path manually in each transformer in the second FMW-script, the script doesn't spit out this error.

Comment: Are you using a feature reader transformer or a standard reader? I've had issues with this version of FME using parameters in feature readers. But, admittedly, not with rasters. Is the parameter a text parameter or a file parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't completely got an explanation, but my theory is when the first FMW-script has to send its published parameters to the second FMW-script, something goes wrong.

I think it interprets the forward slashes ("/") as a special character, not as literal string.

A not-so-elegant solution is to convert the "solidus" back to forward slashes in the second script.